# django migrate from URLField to foreign key without south

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a model that have a URLField field and I need to make a migration that turns this field into a foreign key, where the string is a unique field of the other object, and, if the object does not exist create it.

for example, turn this:

```
class Event_UserVisit(Event_Base):
    dest_url = models.URLField(max_length=1000)
```

into this:

```
class Event_UserVisit(Event_Base):
    dest_url = models.ForeignKey(Page)
```

I've never done a manual migration like this and didn't find any tutorial or instructions to do something like this.

obviously doing a naive migration return errors like this:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "source_url_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
```

what's the best approach to do it?

note: I need to do this on a production db with lots of data, so I can't have long down time and can't lose any data.

thanks! :)

Comment: What version of Django are you using? syncdb  has been "deprecated" and replaced by migrate in Django version 1.7+. It's recommend to use Django's own built in migration tool over South. Both created by Andrew Godwin. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/

Comment: 1.8, but I'm using migrate, not syncdb, without south. I think the problem is legit, eg its not something I'm doing wrong with django, its just something I don't know how to do with django. It's not a trivial migration to convert URL field to foreign key of existing / new objects. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this at the ORM level in one go (unless someone corrects me) You would need create a new FK maybe `dest_url2` run migrations, then write a script to migrate the data. Next,delete `dest_url` again run migrations. Then rename `dest_url2` to `dest_url` Django will detect the name change here.

**However**, I don't understand why you are linking an FK ID on page to a field called `dest_url`. A PK in Page should not be a 1000 max URL! It has no order and would make indexing hard and slow down your app. It would make more sense do have...

```
class Event_UserVisit(Event_Base):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='eventvisits')
```

The I assume Page looks something like this...

```
class Page(models.Model):
    dest_url = models.URLField(max_length=1000)
```

Comment: hi Glyn Jackson, by the time you answered I already did pretty much what you suggested, so I'm happy to see I took the right approach. about the PK thing - I said "primary key" just to keep it simple, but its not really the PK, just a unique field. Pages still use the built-in integer PK. ;) regardless, +1 for the great tip.